# Help with a Series (Edited)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation

The original problem was: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{k}{6k^3+13k^2+9k+2}$$
Using Partial Fractions, I resolved this into 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{6}{3k+2}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{2}{2n+1}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{k+1}$$
From here, whatever I did was evidently wrong. I managed to split the series into the difference of Divergent Series. $$$$Any help on solving these 3 series would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much, and I'm truly sorry for the trouble I've caused by making mistakes the way I did.

Edit: It seems that even the resolving into Partial Fractions was wrong. Please could you help me from the start? I'm really, really sorry for the trouble caused.

Comment: Something is weird here as both series are *divergent*...

Comment: Sir, I'm modifying the problem. Please could you wait?

Comment: @Ttimbuc Sir' I've finally brought back the original problem. Please, if you aren't too annoyed, could you help me out?

Answer (score 3):

We have that our sum equals:
$$S= \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{12}{6n+4}-\frac{6}{6n+3}-\frac{6}{6n+6}\right)=6\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-x^5+2x^3-x^2)\,x^{6n}\,dx$$
hence:
$$ S = 6\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2(-1+x+x^2)}{(1+x)(1-x+x^2)(1+x+x^2)}\,dx $$
and not it is tedious but straightforward to check through partial fraction decomposition that:
$$ S = -\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}-2\log 2+3\log 3. $$

Comment: Thanks Sir. Sir, please could you explain how you broke the sum into Partial Sums? I noticed that the Partial Sums you got were the Partial Sums I had multiplied by an integer.

Comment: Sir, also could you please explain how $$S=6\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-x^5+2x^3-x^2)\,x^{6n}\,dx= 6\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2(-1+x+x^2)}{(1+x)(1-x+x^2)(1+x+x^2)}\,dx?$$ I thought we would have had to reverse the order of Integration and summation.

Comment: @MakeaDifference: The partial sums are exactly the same. $\frac{12}{6k+4}=\frac{6}{3k+2}$, for instance. Then I exploited $\frac{1}{6n+m}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{6n+m-1}\,dx$. To switch the series and the integral is allowed by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Sir could you please explain how you used the Dominated Convergence Theorem to replace the Summation sign with the Integration Sign (if this is what you meant by switch - my English is quite poor so at times I have difficulty in understanding)? I just read the Wikipedia page and was unable to understand.

Comment: No, I won't make this comment section a brief overview on the huge topic of mathematical analysis. Do you know when we are allowed to switch (i.e. exchange) a series and an integral? If not, prove that we allowed to do that at last in this case.

Comment: Alright Sir, I shall try to prove it. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elementary sum

It converges by the integral test but the sum is...
$$\log \left({27 \over 4} \right)-{\pi \over {\sqrt 3}} = 0.0957...$$

I believe this can be proved using complex analysis, but it'd be a lot of work.

So the integral test actually gives an approximation to the sum. Just integrate the partial fractions from 0 to infinity applying the appropriate limits. The integral of the function $F$ is $\ln(9/8)$. This provides an upper bound on the sum $S$ and an estimate.
$$S \sim 0.117...$$

Comment: Sir, I'm really sorry for my errors. Please could you help me out? I've just deleted whatever I had done and have put the original problem back.